"No Script Url Provided" Error when running React Native Project on Xcode
I have been following the react native set up guide from https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started-without-a-framework
and set up the environment according to here https://reactnative.dev/docs/set-up-your-environment.
I have followed everything and once opening up the workspace with Xcode 16.1 and building successfully with the IPhone 16 simulator I get this error:

No idea whats wrong, I am new to Xcode and building IOS apps. I have checked other answers but they all seem to be using the 'react-native' command which I never used, I simply click the run button on Xcode.
What is going on? And what is the solution? What am I missing from the guide?

I'm here with you. I'm trying to run an Expo app on my phone and am getting the same error.

Run npm run ios in the terminal before running from Xcode.
